# Auto redirect from one url to another

Tags: php

I want to auto redirect page after some time.

```
<?
$email2='shakti@gmail.com';

$var = 'location:';
$var .= 'https://www.ymlp.com/api/Contacts.Add?Key=5ESTZPSGT8AFJV5Y2Y4Q&Username=38bf&Email='.$email2.'&GroupID=5';
header ($var);
?>
```

after redirect heder location the result will be showing

```
 <Result>
    <Code>0</Code>
    <Output>shakti@gmail.com has been added</Output>
    </Result>
```

and after showing result i want to redirect to the index.php

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the refresh header like this.

```
header( "refresh:5; url=wherever.php" ); //Redirect page after five seconds.
```

Make sure you put this before any echo statements.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is using javascript. Insert following javascript in header.

```
<?php $var = "https://redirect_to_somewhere.com"; ?>
<script>
setTimeout(function(){
    document.location.href="<?= $var ?>";
},5000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP's [header](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function, to redirect page in x seconds.

```
<?
$seconds=10;
$email2='shakti@gmail.com';
$var .= 'https://www.ymlp.com/api/Contacts.Add?Key=5ESTZPSGT8AFJV5Y2Y4Q&Username=38bf&Email='.$email2.'&GroupID=5';
header("refresh:$seconds;url=$var");
?>
```